# How do you find and classify the critical points of the function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find and classify the critical points of the function 
$$
f(x,y) = 5x^2 + 2xy + 5y^2.
$$
Use the second derivative test to justify your answer.

For critical points I got $(0,0)$. Is that the only critical point?

Comment: Yes, it is the only critical point.

Answer (score 3):

$\nabla f=(10x+2y,2x+10y)=0\Rightarrow 5x+y=0 $ and $5y+x=0$

Therefore, correctly, the only critical point is (0,0).

Can you now classify it?

Comment: It's a minimum. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, taking the second derivatives : $f_{xx}=10,f_{yy}=10,f_{xy}=f_{yx}=2$. 
Now, $\Delta= f_{xx}f_{yy}-f^2_{xy}=96>0$, thus we have a local extremum. Since $f_{xx}>0 $, it is a local minimum , $f(0,0)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

What @Dimitris found is a critical point. Note as $f_{xx}=10,f_{yy}=10,f_{xy}=2$ so $\Delta_1=f_{xx}>0$ and $\Delta_2=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f^2_{xy}=100-4>0$ and therefore the origin is a local min for $f(x,y)$.

[image]

Comment: Very nice and great picture +1

Comment: Beautiful! $\Large +1$